# What is the term for a program that consumes a dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, node-modules

I am currently working on an update to a package, which other programs use as a dependency.

I'm curious what the correct term is for those dependency-consuming programs from the perspective of the dependency itself.

It isn't quite a peerDependency since the dependency in question is designed to be modular. So when talking about the dep itself, what do you call the other programs that depend on it?

Comment: What's wrong with `dependents`? This term is used by `npm`, among other things.

Comment: I searched a bit through the docs and don't see this term used there. `dependents` is referenced through several npm modules however; in some cases this is elaborated upon with the phrase `package dependents`.

Comment: @Christophe Yes, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### "Dependents" (with a few variants)

Interestingly enough, there appear to be several different terms to refer to a program that consumes a dependency:

- Dependents
- Package Dependents
- Reverse Dependencies
- NPM Dependents

These terms are gathered from SO questions that refer to the same thing. "Dependents" is the term used most frequently; however, the usage of other terms implies that there is some ambiguity around this naming scheme.